# Objective c -- get a list of parents of a protocol

Tags: objective-c, ios, protocols, objective-c-runtime

The [Objective C runtime reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ObjCRuntimeRef/Reference/reference.html) has the function class_getSuperclass for getting the superclass of a class.  Is there anything similar for listing the direct ancestors of a protocol?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's no such thing as ancestors, since protocols expand rather than inherit, hence you should look for siblings. The closest thing that I can give you is:

1. Get the list of protocols with `objc_protocol_list`
2. Check if protocol conforms to protocol with `protocol_conformsToProtocol`

**update** it seems i didn't rtfm enough. Here's the proper method:

`protocol_copyProtocolList`, which is described as

> Returns an array of the protocols adopted by a protocol.

Comment: Looks like I didn't RTFM too well either.